# How to pass dynamic parameters to a MySQL view

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, mysql-workbench

I have created the following view in MySQL:

```
CREATE VIEW MYVIEW AS (
SELECT A.FNAME
     , A.LNAME
     , B.EMAIL
FROM EMPLOYEE A, EMPEMAIL B
WHERE A.EID = :empId
  AND A.EID = B.EID
AND B.EMAILTYP = :emailType)
```

I have to make `empId` and `emailType` dynamic i.e. get the result for the desired values of `empId` and `emailType` at runtime.

What changes should be made in the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just create the view without the parameters (i.e., to take care of the join only):

```
CREATE VIEW MYVIEW AS (
SELECT A.FNAME
     , A.LNAME
     , B.EMAIL
     , A.EID AS EID             -- added to be used in the WHERE
     , B.EMAILTYP AS EMAILTYP   -- added to be used in the WHERE
FROM EMPLOYEE A, EMPEMAIL B
WHERE A.EID = B.EID)
```

And apply the dynamic parameters when you query:

```
SELECT FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL
FROM   my_view
WHERE  eid = 'your_empId' AND emailtyp = 'your_emailType'
```

Note the `WHERE` shown above, it uses the two extra fields declared in the `VIEW`

Comment: Thanx for reply But i did not want show values of  A.EID  B.EMAILTYP in resultant columns . what change should i made???

Comment: just query the fields that you want - I amended my answer to show that.

Comment: i want to select only three column --> A.FNAME, A.LNAME, B.EMAIL

Comment: When we need to perform parametrized WHERE clause, we need to skip some records, in Your implementation it is OKAY unless somebody thinks one can fetch all records and then perfom it manually on great data-sets. The problem of parametrized view is still unsolved

Comment: The issue here is that the view will grab a much larger dataset than you may want. This is my current issue, where I need to use a dynamic `WHERE` inside my view or my performance tanks.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell since the SQL of the view is executed at runtime, I do think the query optimizer would optimize the view with filters the same way it would optimize the SQL with filters given directly. (note: this is speculation; an `EXPLAIN PLAN` should tell the real story). @javababa selecting stored columns is cheap. If you just want three columns, just select those from the view. don't think about overoptimizing the view.

Answer (score 17):

You can use this solution with a function -

```
CREATE FUNCTION func() RETURNS int(11)
  RETURN @var;

CREATE VIEW view1 AS
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = func();
```

Using example:

```
SET @var = 1;
SELECT * FROM view1;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL views behaves like a table;

Say your view is;

```
CREATE VIEW view_fetch_part_data AS
SELECT 
p.new_study_no, 
p.study_no AS fk_part, 
p.is_participant_available, 
p.part_unavailable_reason, 
p.name, 
p.sync_date AS part_syncdate,
ca.timepoint, 
ca.is_participant_available AS ca_participant_available, 
ca.part_unavailable_reason AS ca_part_unavailable_reason,  
ca.last7days_child_symptoms, 
ca.illness_timeOff_days, 
hm.names AS hm_names, 
hm.age AS hm_age, 
hm.sex AS hm_sex, 
hm.relationship, 
FROM participants p 
LEFT JOIN clinical_assessments ca
ON p.study_no = ca.fk_part 
LEFT JOIN hh_members hm
ON p.study_no = hm.fk_part 
LEFT JOIN hh_rooms hr
ON p.study_no = hr.fk_part ;
```

Executing it will get you;

```
SELECT * FROM view_fetch_part_data
```

[image: view of the query]

Then apply where clause just like a normal table;

```
SELECT * FROM view_fetch_part_data WHERE fk_part = 211123;
```