# create a view with query result used in another query that need dynamic parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query and I use sails.js to replace ? with int:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT message.from AS UserID FROM message WHERE message.from = ? or message.to = ? UNION SELECT message.to FROM message)
group by user.id
```

my search lead me to this stackoverflow page
[how pass dynamic parameter in mysql view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946526/how-pass-dynamic-parameter-in-mysql-view)
the problem is I couldn't do it, if I replaced ? with user.id and create alias calling it userID, it doesn't get passed or saved as the answer says.
I get error in Sql that userId doesn't exist.

Comment: when you use sub query not need alias name.. like as UserID

Comment: Okay I don't need UserID, yet I want to create view and be able to pass a paramter

Comment: Refer this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html