# MySql view with group_by very slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `appointments` and `clients`. The tables are big, each with about 100M records.

- each has a primary key on `id`
- `clients` has a foreign key on `appointment_id`

I'm using mysql 5.7

As one would expect, the following query is lightning fast:

```
select a.id, count(c.id) client_count
from appointments a
left join clients c on c.appointment_id = a.id
where a.id = 499
group by a.id;
```

But, if I create the following view and query, it is interminably **slow**:

```
create view client_counts as
select a.id, count(c.id) client_count
from appointments a
left join clients c on c.appointment_id = a.id
group by a.id;

select id, client_count
from client_counts
where id = 499;
```

I'm assuming the where clause is not being applied to the inner query (in the view), but rather every record of the view must be scanned to see if 499 is a match. I think this is caused by the `group by`.

Note: I did see that I can [use a function in the where clause of the view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19948251/1040598), but it seems very clunky. Is this the preferred method?

My Question: What's the best way I can continue to use a view and have it be fast?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved especially indexes (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Append the plans for both queries (direct and via the view).

Comment: For that specific query, you can probably have `CREATE INDEX client_app_ndx ON clients(appointment_id); CREATE VIEW client_counts AS SELECT appointment_id AS id, COUNT (*) AS client_count FROM clients`;

Comment: The "best way" to deal with this may be to upgrade your MySQL version. MySQL 5.7 is already rather old. They've probably made some enhancements to the optimizer since then. You may be lucky they already addressed your problem in the current version. MySQL 8 was a big leap in my opinion with the introduction of CTEs (plain and recursive) and window functions. For these reasons alone, I'd already recommend the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use a function; if you were using Postgres, maybe using a `materialized view` could solve your problem if the records don't change much... but in general I think you should use a function here, or just do a query instead of using a view.

Anyway, it's a good idea to check if the id fields are indexed.

Comment: Thanks. fields are indexed. Function is fast, but seems very clunky.  Writing it out as a big (I simplified it for posting) subquery (I am doing another group by) also works.

Comment: @FelixLivni - Caution; a "simplified" query gives you a "simplified" answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Your first query does not really use `c`.  So, I don't consider it worth discussing.
- `COUNT(x)` checks each `x` for being not NULL.  Usually people use `COUNT(*)` to count "rows".
- `VIEWs` are syntactic sugar; I have yet to see an example where a `VIEW` runs faster than the equivalent `SELECT`.  I have seen many cases where the `VIEW` seems to run significantly slower.
- Would you like to discuss how to write the optimal `SELECT` to achieve some 'count'?

I think your View + Select boil down to simply

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients WHERE appointment_id = 499;
```

That query will be lightning fast if `clients` has

```
INDEX(appointment_id)
```

(Sorry, MySQL is not smart enough to deduce this for you.)

**More**

Let's take another approach.  See if the following VIEW definition works correctly for you:

```
CREATE VIEW client_counts AS
    SELECT a.id,
           ( SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM clients
               WHERE appointment_id = a.id
           ) AS client_count
        FROM appointments a;
```

Note that turning the query inside out avoids the need for `GROUP BY`.  This may help performance.

Check that you have this index:

```
clients:  INDEX(appointment_id)
```

I assume that `a` has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`?

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. I meant to write count(c.id) not count(a.id).

I don't expect the view to run faster than an equivalent select. I was hoping to get similar performance.

Comment: I want a view because it provides a nice abstraction for many other queries that would use it. Yes, "syntactic sugar" as you say, but very helpful in the case that I have.

Comment: @FelixLivni - Yes, "abstraction" is a good reason for having a View.  I rewrote the view; see if it works and is faster.

Comment: Thanks @rick. Your newer solution is much faster than the original view, but still many orders of magnitude slower than just setting the id in the where clause directly. I do have index on `appointment_id`  and a.id is a primary key. NOTE: Without the index, my first query would have been very slow due to the join using c.appointment_id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the optimizer in MySQL 5.7 is not good enough yet to fully understand the query and apply the condition early. You are right, this is probably due to aggregation. What the DBMS sees is this:

```
select id, client_count
from
(
  select a.id, count(c.id) client_count
  from appointments a
  left join clients c on c.appointment_id = a.id
  group by a.id;
) client_counts
where id = 499;
```

which it can reduce to

```
select a.id, count(c.id) client_count
from appointments a
left join clients c on c.appointment_id = a.id
group by a.id
having a.id = 499;
```

but it doesn't see that the condition can be moved before the aggregation.

I am pretty sure you can workaround this by not aggregating over the joined rows, but over clients only. This is done by moving the aggregation into a subquery and place it in the select clause. (MySQL doesn't feature lateral joins yet, otherwise you'd have the choice to put the correlated subquery in the from clause instead.)

```
create view client_counts as
select
  a.id, 
  (
    select count(*)
    from clients c
    where c.appointment_id = a.id
  ) as client_count
from appointments a;
```

Comment: Thanks @thorsten.  I agree with the your first two code snippets and the following conclusion. The third snippet is essentially what rick has now posted. I gave it a shot and although it is faster than what I had (and also your first two snippets), it is still orders of magnitude slower than setting the id in the where clause directly. So far, the function is the only way that I've come across that works. I'll likely just construct the complex sql in code and forgo the nice abstraction that you get with views.